# Programs to log NMEA on Nomad 900?

Tags: data, convert, gps

I am interested in logging NMEA data on a Trimble Nomad 900. Unfortunately the SatViewer records a maximum of 64,000 characters, too little for my application. I don't want to have to purchase Terrasync/Pathfinder because I already have tools to parse NMEA and those pieces of software are overkill for my intended use. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with [gvsig mobile](https://joinup.ec.europa.eu/software/gvsig-mobile/release/120). It is little buggy but if I remember correctly it can record NMEA to a file.